# Normal subgroups are not transitive, but $H \subseteq N \lhd G, H \lhd G \implies H \lhd N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H,N,G$ be groups where $H \subseteq N \subseteq G$. For the 3 statements below:

1. $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$: $ghg^{-1} \in H \ \forall h \in H, \forall g \in G$
2. $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$: $gng^{-1} \in N \ \forall n \in n, \forall g \in G$
3. $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$: $nhn^{-1} \in H \ \forall h \in H, \forall n \in N$

Is 1 enough to imply 3?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you!

Comment: Yes infact you did not even need N to be normal in G. Just H being normal in G was enough.

Comment: @Mustang Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we just let $g=n$:

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $ghg^{-1} \in H \ \forall h \in H, \forall g \in G$ including $n \in N \subseteq G$

Therefore, not only

$H \subseteq N \lhd G, H \lhd G \implies H \lhd N$

but also

$H \subseteq N \subset G, H \lhd G \implies H \lhd N$?